# Why might need include a source file that?

Tags: c

I am to port `h264` codec in an embedded device. The ffmpeg source code uses the following construction:

```
#undef  CHROMA_IDC
#define CHROMA_IDC 3
#include "h264_mc_template.c"

static av_noinline void FUNC(hl_decode_mb_444)(const H264Context *h, H264SliceContext *sl)
{
    ...
}
```

Why do I need to include such a source file? Isn't that used only for the header?

Comment: So is the question why a C file is being included? The question is a bit hard to understand for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: `h264_mc_template.c` must depend on `CHROMA_IDC` so it needs inclusion to generate the proper code.

Comment: Do yew mean why a source file is included?

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "template" suffix hints at the fact that the code depends on some preprocessor directives.

I checked the [source](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/h264__mc__template_8c_source.html) and at the beginning there's

```
   #if   CHROMA_IDC == 1
   #   define MCFUNC(n) FUNC(n ## _420)
   #elif CHROMA_IDC == 2
   #   define MCFUNC(n) FUNC(n ## _422)
   #elif CHROMA_IDC == 3
   #   define MCFUNC(n) FUNC(n ## _444)
   #endif
```

note that you have `#define CHROMA_IDC 3` *before* including this file.

This tells the preprocessor to use `define MCFUNC(n) FUNC(n ## _444)` in the included file.

the source *could* have been left alone in the makefile but with a `-DCHROMA_IDC=3` directive, and in that case, the template cannot be reused for other source files because of multiple redefinition (the functions in this source file are `static` to avoid multiple redefinition if the template is instanciated more than once)

Why using a template? probably for performance issues, to avoid a call chain and some tests to branch on the required behaviour. `ffmpeg` cannot afford to be slow on the encoding functions.